# Retrieving value of a label in which is binded to an element value

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In my current scenario (WPF, MVVM), I have a user control which hosts a visio diagram. This user control is located on a view, next to a number of labels and a datagrid element.

The user control contains a DependencyProperty object `SelectedNode` which value is updated with the information received from the Visio diagram. The labels' content are binded so that they display the information contained in the `SelectedNode` (e.g. id, name):

```
<Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="lbNodeIdValue" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                           Content="{Binding ElementName=visioControlUC, Path=SelectedNode.Id, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Every time I change the selection in the diagram, the label's content changes as expected.

Next to this label, I would like to display a datagrid containing information based on the id displayed in the label. This is where I ran into problems, as I can't seem to be able to get the value of the `Content` property of the label in the viewmodel class.

I have tried using the `MultiBinding` property on the `Content` element of the label, and creating a second binding with `Mode=OneWayToSource` to set the value of the label's `Content` to a property I have defined in the viewmodel class.

What would be a proper way to retrieve this value in my viewmodel class?

Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally your Datagrid's `ViewModel` should get the value of the selected label from the other `ViewModel`. You should not rely on `Views` to transfer application data between `ViewModels`.

It sounds like the `SelectedNode` value originates from the `UserControl`, and not the `ViewModel`, so you'll need to bind the `UserControl.SelectedNodeId` to a `ViewModel` somewhere so the ViewModels have access to this data

```
<local:myUserControl x:Name="visioControlUC" 
                     SelectedNode="{Binding SelectedNodeId}" />
```

If the value is needed by more than one `ViewModel`, I would highly recommend some kind of event system, such as MVVM Light's `Messenger` or Prism's `EventAggregator`. This would allow your `ViewModels` to subscribe to something like a `SelectedNodeChangedEventMessage`, and the `ViewModel` which actually contains the `SelectedNodeId` can broadcast that message anytime the value changes. You can find an example of both on my blog post about [Communication between ViewModels](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/communication-between-viewmodels-with-mvvm/).

Comment: Yeap, that was it.. I was not looking to set anything in the user control, but I used your suggestion and it works.

Thanks a lot :)